# Ruby's native header files are giving me an error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

When I include  in my native C extension for a gem that I am writing, I get the following error:

```
../../../../ext/my_file/my_file.c:4:42: error: unknown type name 'RUBY_T_FIXNUM'
```

Here is where I use it in my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h>

void my_file_init(const T_STRING prog, T_FIXNUM verbose) {}
```

I added a link in /usr/local/include to ~/.rvm/rubies/default/include/ruby-2.3.0, which is where I have the version of ruby that I want to use installed. The only definition I could find for the T_FIXNUM constant in the ruby header files was within an enum in ruby/ruby.h:

```
enum ruby_value_type {
    ...
    RUBY_T_FIXNUM = 0x15
};
```

Here is where the ruby/ruby.h file defines the T_FIXNUM type:

```
#define T_FIXNUM RUBY_T_FIXNUM
```

Am I including files incorrectly? Do I have the wrong version of Ruby? I'm working on OSX and I use RVM to manage my rubies. I have added symbolic links for config.h in the x86_64-darwin16/ruby dir, as well as a link from the ruby dir to itself.

Comment: You need to give more code, like a minimal example that can help reproduce this. A short snippet like this isn't very informative.

Comment: Thanks, I added where I use the type in my code as well as where that type is defined within ruby's code. Is that enough

Comment: You need to give even more, like where your `#include` statements are and such. This is like looking through a drinking straw at your problem.

Comment: I added pretty much the entirety of my C file.